# Can I make my window (session?) manager remember what workspace to place a window in?

Tags: gnome, window-manager, session-manager

I use Gnome on a RHEL system.  When I launch a new program, the window manager (?) seems to make an effort to remember the size and position of the window when I last used it.  However, I don't know how I can get it to remember what *workspace* it was last on.

Actually, bonus question: ideally, I'd like to be able to have a single program (in my case, Firefox) launch with different windows on different workspaces.  They're set up this way when I log off, and I'd like them to come back the same way the following day when I log back in.

Comment: What Window Manager are you using? Metacity? Compiz? Unity? Something else?

Comment: So kinda like how Lion works?

Comment: Haven't used Lion.  And I think I may be too much of a Linux-newb to answer the window manager question.  GDM I think?  `gdm-binary` shows up in `ps`.

Comment: the term you are searching for is 'session-manager' (not so much 'window manager')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This [previous question](https://superuser.com/questions/232042/ubuntu-gnome-open-an-application-is-a-specific-workspace) seems to provide a solution: you can use Devil's Pie to programmatically move your app windows to the correct workspaces based on certain properties (program name, window title, etc.)

If you want a fully dynamic behavior, you can probably run a script at logout time that records which program is on which workspace, but having not used Devil's Pie myself I'm not sure how much work that'd be.

Comment: I'm going to take this as "you can't do this natively" and assume that if I cared enough to do so, I could use the program you suggest.  Thanks!