# A bash script to start applications in certain workspaces

Tags: ubuntu, bash-scripting, cinnamon

I'm dreaming of a Bash script that opens applications and places them in certain workspaces.

For example, I'd like to run a script that:

- In Workspace 1 opens firefox
- WS2 - opens term and maximizes it
- WS3 - opens Sublime Text2 and maximizes it
- WS4 - opens Pidgin, gpodder, and banshee

Is such a script possible in Ubuntu 13.04 running Cinnamon?

Comment: What OS and window manager?

Comment: Just added to post. Cinnamon on Ubuntu 13.04

Answer (score 0):

Yes, [devilspie](https://wiki.gnome.org/DevilsPie) or [wmctrl](http://linux.die.net/man/1/wmctrl) would do something close to what I'm asking. Link [Ubuntu/ Gnome : Open an application in a specific workspace – wingedsubmariner](https://superuser.com/questions/232042/ubuntu-gnome-open-an-application-in-a-specific-workspace) left in the commets by @wingedsubmariner led me to these two utilities.

Essentially to answer the question -- once programs have been opened...

wmctrl -r mozilla -t 0
wmctrl -r mozilla -t 1